# Octave not running in VS Code despite installing extensions and setting paths

Tags: visual-studio-code, octave

Unable to run Octave in VS Code even after installing all the Octave extensions and adding the below path to settings.json:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Octave": {
        "path": "C:\\Program Files\\GNU Octave\\Octave-7.1.0\\mingw64\\bin\\octave-7.1.0.bat",
        "args": []
    }
},
```

and adding the Octave GUI path to environment variables as well.

How can I run my Octave files in VS Code? I want to integrate them with a Python file in same directory.

Comment: Not a VSCode user but presumably the path shouldn't include the "octave-7.1.0.bat" bit, since that's not a directory, that's the actual batchscript used to implicitly call the octave executable. If VSCode further expects the actual executable somewhere, I would also guess that you'd need the actual .exe file rather than the batchscript.

Comment: Yes my path was incorrect. It's working now!